# Ошибка в описании к знаку "Бродяга"

Tags: дефект, дизайн, знаки, профиль-участника

В описании полученного знака "Бродяга" название вопроса имеет длинный заголовок, который вылазит за границы блока:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> django.contib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage.
>   Ошибка при выполнении python3
>   manage.py collectstatic

Comment: Про ошибку в самом движке сайта?

Comment: Ошибка в верстке, я скинул ее в "связаться с нами" сейчас скину сюда.

Comment: @Max, я правильно понял проблему. Это не просто длинный заголовок, это программная ошибка... Вместо описания выводится что-то вроде stack trace ошибки.

Comment: @Max, а вылезает за границы блока, потому что первая строка считается за одно слово, но основная проблема не в этом, а как раз в ошибке загрузки локализованной строчки описания условий получения знака

Comment: @VenZell вряд ли это стектрейс. Там ошибка из django (python), а этот сайт написан на C#.

Comment: @VenZell в заголовке вопроса не выводится ошибка сайта stackoverflow, это заголовок вопроса. В нем присутствует - 'django.contib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'. А ошибка в том, что эта длинная строка вылазит за границы блока(скриншот).